# when i pass a variable from the main method, my app crash

Tags: android

im using android studio and im making an app but i have this problem when i pass the variable from my main to the class, my app crash.

its show me a massage that the app has stopped

this is how i pass the variable

```
 bravo b = new bravo();
        b.updatetext(Correctcounter);
```

and this is my method in the class

```
public void updatetext(int x) {
   TextView scoreView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
   scoreView.setText(""+x);
}
```

Comment: please post the stacktrace of your crash.. it's difficult to find the error without that

Comment: Is Correctcounter an int? It looks like an Object to me. Also, what is the crash?

Comment: Correctcounter is an int

Answer (score 0):

**You can't access views from classes that are not UI.**

You should **never** access a view from a custom class.

**Views must be accessed from Activity or Fragment!**

Change your logic to match this requirement.

Comment: but you can't use `findViewById()` in a custom class... Why do you know that @samir saadi is using a class that is not a fragment or activity?

Comment: Thats right... so maybe he extended some android class to use `findViewById()`. And initialized it the wrong way

Comment: im new for android i thought that i can pass the varable like that

Comment: ill change my logic thanks for help

Comment: If your view R.id.score is inside activity A, you must access it through activity A. You can't find a view from Activity A inside Activity B.